# NOT NULL constraint failed - django

Tags: django

This is similar to a question i posted a while ago, but i have a different situation. I have a model with a form that is attached to the model. I am getting an not null constraint, but there is no field that is null so the constraint fail should not be coming up. I am not sure where this constraint fail is coming from... can someone help me just in case i dont see it.

models.py

```
dob_month = models.IntegerField(default=0)
dob_day = models.IntegerField(default=0)
dob_year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py section

```
dob_month = form.cleaned_data.get("dob_month")
dob_day = form.cleaned_data.get("dob_day")
dob_year = form.cleaned_data.get("dob_year")

new_profile = Profile.objects.create(
                user = currentUser,
                first_name = first_name,
                last_name = last_name,
                dob_month = dob_month,
                dob_day = dob_day,
                dob_year = dob_year,
                city = city,
                state = state,
                phone = phone,
                privacy = privacy,
)
```

form post request

```
dob_month : '6'
dob_day : '14'
dob_year : '2019'
```

here is the exact error that is coming up...

```
IntegrityError at /setup_profile/
NOT NULL constraint failed: tab_profile.dob_day
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/setup_profile/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: tab_profile.dob_day
```

UPDATED

Here is the forms.py section...

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    split_choices = (('1', 'public'),
                     ('2', 'private'))
    privacy = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=split_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect, coerce=int
    )
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'city', 'state', 'phone', 'privacy']
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess the problem is occurring due to string insertion in the numeric field

so try this, hope it will solve the error

```
new_profile = Profile.objects.create(
                user = currentUser,
                first_name = first_name,
                last_name = last_name,
                dob_month = int(dob_month),
                dob_day = int(dob_day),
                dob_year = int(dob_year),
                city = city,
                state = state,
                phone = phone,
                privacy = privacy,
)
```

Comment: I tried what you said and i am still getting the same error... not sure how to fix it... @Exprator

Comment: i am adding the form for the file int eh updated section of the post... could that be it.... @Exprator